# Visualizing the cluster doesn't give me the expected result

Tags: neo4j

I got the cluster using WCC:

When I do `groupSize>2` I ended up getting nodes without any link.

```
MATCH (c:User)
WITH c.clusterGroup AS fpGroupID, collect(id(c)) AS fGroup
WITH *, size(fGroup) AS groupSize WHERE groupSize > 2 
WITH collect(fpGroupID) AS cRings
MATCH p=(c:User)-[:REL]->()
WHERE c.clusterGroup IN cRings

RETURN p
```

---

[image]

But when I do `groupSize=2` or `groupSize<=2` or `groupSize <=6 and groupSize >= 1`

I get:

[image]

Note I am getting edges also.

but why does it fails for `groupSize > threshold` i.e `>` or `>=` sign

**Cluster Data:**

[image]

### Note: I have kept the `connect result nodes` as `off`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On your neo4j desktop, increase the values of Node display, max neighbors and max rows so that you will see the nodes including the relationships (links).

[image]

Comment: It helped.  Although the results are mess :(. Cluster are not perfect they are interconnected also.